# Android androidx.SearchView is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, searchview

I have implemented SearchView in MaterialToolBar in my project. Everything working fine except for the final step. When I type anything in the search bar and click on the keyboard find button, it doesn't show anything. Please help.

Video of my problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GpE16D3drLGYp0ZetHgNlT8s7qZSFuWk/view?usp=drivesdk

Menu.xml

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
```

activity.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/category1_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    app:menu="@menu/cart_share"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back_all_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_all_categories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/product_name"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginStart="25sp"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
```

java code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart_search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Type here to search");
    searchView.setMaxWidth(android.R.attr.width);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //getSearchResults(query); Also tried
            getSearchResults(searchView.getQuery().toString());
            if( ! searchView.isIconified()) {
                searchView.setIconified(true);
            }
            menuItem.collapseActionView();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: did you add `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>` ?

Comment: yeah   `<activity android:name=".product.ProductListActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: check my code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the sequence of code lines after that it worked fine.

**Before:**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.category1_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
```

**After:**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.category1_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart_search_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        
        SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                
                // your code
                
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // your code
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code now and before also but not working in my case, check the video I have attached you will understand the problem.

Comment: In logcat it is not showing anything related to the error.

Comment: @VaibhavA Solved this yet?

Comment: Yes, amiya I solved this by swapping two lines. Check my above answer. Can you please tell me why this was not working?

Comment: @VaibhavA big mistake. you should execute `setContentView` first.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjYjA.jpg)try this

in menu file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/actionTenantSearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    />
```

In kotlin file:

```
  private var searchItem : MenuItem? = null
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_tenant_menu, menu)
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionTenantSearch)

    val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object :
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(s: String): Boolean {
            CommonUtils.showToast(requireContext(), s)
            searchView.clearFocus()
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(s: String): Boolean {

            return true
        }
    })
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@vaibhav have you implemented filterable class to your listview or recyclerview. After that call that filterable method in on your search query. You will get appropriate reault
Like this

public class Adaptername extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

}

CustomFilter filter;

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null) {
        filter = new CustomFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}

class CustomFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            //CONSTARINT TO UPPER
            constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            ArrayList<AllInOnetItem> filters = new ArrayList<AllInOnetItem>();
            //get specific items
            for (int i = 0; i < filterList.size(); i++) {
                if (filterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                    AllInOnetItem p = new AllInOnetItem(filterList.get(i).getName(), filterList.get(i).getNumber(),filterList.get(i).getEmail());
                    filters.add(p);
                }
            }
            results.count = filters.size();
            results.values = filters;
        } else {
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        allInOnetItems = (ArrayList<AllInOnetItem>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not using the filter. My solution is listed above.

Answer (score -1):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.PrimarySurface"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
        app:menu="@menu/menu2"
       >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/mySearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:clipToOutline="false"
            app:queryHint="Search"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />
```

Answer (score -2):

///MainActivity

binding.mySearch.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
return false
}

```
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return false
            }
        })
```